# REST implementation on OSGi Jetty using web.xml

Tags: java, rest, jetty, osgi

Trying a simple REST implementation on OSGi Jetty using web.xml

Below repository contains the code which I tried:
https://github.com/pkolanda/my-learning-osgi-simple-rest-with-jetty
 to run the code, mvn clean install and run the run.sh shell script under the target/my-learning-osgi-simple-rest-with-jetty-0.1 folder.

To run the code, git close and mvn clean install .. in the traget folder, there is run.sh just run that script.

I tried looking for a configuration related issue. I could not exact error message with this problem.

Below are the details of my implementation:

Resource file:

```
@Path("jsonstatus")
public class JsonResource {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JsonResource.class);

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String listConferences() {
        logger.info("Returning the status");
        return "{\"status\": \"success\"}";
    }
}
```

Application Implementation:

```
public class JerseyApplication extends Application {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JerseyApplication.class.getName());
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        logger.info("--Returning all the claess-");
        Set<Class<?>> result = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        result.add(JsonResource.class);
        result.add(StatusResource.class);
        return result;
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>JAXRSEx</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>my.learnings.osgi.rest.jetty.activator.JerseyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAXRSEx</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

All the OSGi core, console and jetty jars are added: When I start the Equinox, i get the below error. I dont have the activator mapped to bundle and i deployed using web.xml

It works with the Simple Activator:

```
@Override
public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Starting the bundle");
    ServletContextHandler ch = new ServletContextHandler();
    ch.setContextPath("/");
    ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer());
    holder.setInitParameter("javax.ws.rs.Application", JerseyApplication.class.getName());
    ch.addServlet(holder, "/*");
    context.registerService(ContextHandler.class.getName(), ch, null);
}
```

I expect to get the application jar deployed without error.

Below is the error i am getting:

```
05:59:46.779 [Start Level: Equinox Container: 82edcca2-ba11-4354-8c49-96dd914910fc] WARN  o.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext - Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@70993f30{/controller/nb/v2/monitor,file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8081-my-learning-osgi-simple-rest-with-jetty-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar-_controller_nb_v2_monitor-any-1013570667046445682.dir/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{file:/home/ndb/dev/my-learning-osgi-simple-rest-with-jetty/target/my-learning-osgi-simple-rest-with-jetty-0.1/plugins/my-learning-osgi-simple-rest-with-jetty-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser$MyClassVisitor.<init>(AnnotationParser.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:935)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.osgi.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.osgi.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$BundleParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:471)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
____________________________
Welcome to Apache Felix Gogo

g!
```

Comment: The ASM exception probably indicates the version of ASM does not understand the class file version of a class file it is being asked to process.

Comment: Thanks BJ Hargrave.. I tried to update ASM before.. somehow it did not work.. now this i  did very carefully.. it worked...

https://github.com/pkolanda/my-learning-osgi-simple-rest-with-jetty/commit/6baefad91989cd5885151e97ee2adf7d7c55455d

Above is the change i made.. but not able to access the REST resource..

Comment: <Web-ContextPath>/test</Web-ContextPath> made it working.. i am able to access the resource. Updated the code in the repo